# How can I make Finder display correct 'today' date?

Tags: finder

'All my files' shows 'today' as three days ago - even though I've done all kinds of work since then.

Any fixes?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the date field is the created date-rather than the modified date? If so, change the displayed properties to the modified date.